# Simple Jenkins pipeline build failing due to Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

Under the Global Tools Configuration, under Maven installations: I have the name as 'maven_3_5_4' and version as 3.5.4 and 'Install Automatically' is checked.

Below is my Jenkinsfile code:

```
pipeline {

agent any
tools {
    maven 'maven_3_5_4'
  }
stages {

    stage ('Compile Stage') {

        steps {

                sh 'maven clean compile'
        }
    }
    stage ('Testing Stage') {

        steps {

                sh 'maven test'
        }
    }
}
}
```

While building the pipeline, I am getting the below error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline_JenkinsDemo@tmp/durable-975c8dc3/script.sh: maven: not found
```

I am able to build the project using a Maven project in Jenkins. Then, I moved on to get hands-on on how to deal with pipelines. This is my first Jenkins pipeline and the build is failing. I am not sure how the build is successful when building as a maven project and failing when building the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool is called maven but the command to use on shell is `mvn`.
This is why you get the `maven: not found` error. Correct your pipeline sh and it should run.

```
 sh 'mvn clean compile'
```